# Github pages & jquery cookie; state saved on page level only

Tags: cookies, github, github-pages

So I just put an old project on github. It was in PHP and had some cookie magic so that when 
you "invert" the colors it would stay through the site. I saved a rendered HTML version of the the site for github and I also switched all the cookie magic to jquery.cookie so that it would work without a server-side component

There's a link to the site below.

http://reggi.github.io/csi-bp

So it seems that github pages set cookies on a page-level and they don't seem to transfer between pages. Is this the case? I'm curious as to what I'm missing.

I know they just switched the domain from github.com to github.io for cookie / security purposes, but I didn't know that it was going to result in this.

Comment: It works for me, though.

Comment: Is there any side-effect from https://github.com/blog/1477-content-security-policy ?

Comment: @SohamChowdhury my site or did you try your own?

Comment: @ThomasReggi sure, I have added it as an answer in case it helps.

Comment: @ThomasReggi I tried the site that you linked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It could be a side effect of the newest security measure from GitHub (April 18th):

"[Content Security Policy](https://github.com/blog/1477-content-security-policy)"

> [Content Security Policy](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSP/) is a new HTTP header that provides a solid safety net against XSS attacks.
>   It does this by **blocking inline scripts** and **limiting the domains that other scripts can be loaded from**.